# Open file with OS's default application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Im trying to open a file using the OS's default application, so if i open `image.png` on mac it will open with `Preview` and on windows `Windows Photo Viewer` etc.

Im aware that on OSX you can do `open image.png`, but what about windows and linux? Is there a command to open any file with the default application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on windows it's `start "filename"`

Answer (score 0):

I havent done much testing but from googling around it looks like i've found something that *should* work.

```js
function open(path) {
    let command = '';
    switch (process.platform) {
        case 'darwin':
            command = 'open';
            break;
        case 'win32':
            command = 'start';
            break;
        default:
            command = 'xdg-open';
            break;
    }
    return child_process.execSync(`${command} "${path}"`);
}
```

Comment: the windows one has a typo and is wrong aswell, because `explorer test.zip` would open the zip file in the explorer, while `start test.zip` open's my default programm WinRAR

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz interesting, does `start ./folderName` open the folder in explorer folder?

Comment: indeed it does open it in explorer

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz alright, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

for windows you can just type the file name as `test.png` to open it, for linux (ubuntu) you can use `xdg-open "filename"`