# get list of installed programs that can open file type

Tags: node.js, electron, node.js-fs

There are approximately a million questions about how to open a file in a default app using node and electron, including:
[open a file with default program in node-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902347/open-a-file-with-default-program-in-node-webkit)
[NodeJS open local file using the default preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130340/nodejs-open-local-file-using-the-default-preview)
[Open file with OS's default application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145053/open-file-with-oss-default-application)

I'm interested in opening a file in a NON-default application. So for example, in my electron application, if a user right-clicks on a file they should be able to get a list of currently installed software that can open a file type, and then open it.

I'm pretty sure I understand how to open a file once I know which application/executable to use -- I can simply call the shell, or use the [app option in open](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open#readme). But I have no idea how to query the OS for installed programs that can open a specific file type.

Would appreciate any tips!

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: ideally any OS, but prioritizing mac os for now

Comment: I wonder if you're overextending your scope.  Should each application on my computer be responsible for providing features to allow me to open a file using an application of my choice?  Or should that feature itself be part of my shell? Typically I would just convey an intent to the shell to open the file and it would handle opening the file according to my (global) preferences. It may not just be a matter of knowing which application--there may be additional arguments required to open the file successfully with the target app. I think you should respect the os association and use an _intent_.

Comment: I'm explicitly building a file system, so being able to open files using a choice of applications is pretty important

Comment: You may find the superuser.com question [Where does Mac OS X store file association information?](https://superuser.com/q/20822) relevant.